# PHP Time since does not work

Tags: php

I have a problem with my PHP code
I tried to make a time since (notification was sent) thing and it doesnt work. And I don't get why.. I searched on stackoverflow what I was doing wrong

This is my code

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
$SN = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM notif WHERE send_to IN ('{$_SESSION['user_name']}') ORDER BY not_id DESC LIMIT 4");
$SN->execute();

$NN = $SN->rowCount();
if ($NN == 0)
{
    print("<br><div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Je hebt geen notificaties!</div>");
}
while ($row = $SN->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo " <li>
          <i class='{$row['not_icon']}'></i>
           <div class='font-w600'>{$row['send_by']}</div>
            <div><a href='javascript:void(0)'>{$row['notif_text']}</a></div>
                            ";



$time = $row['date_send'];

}

echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time).' ago';

function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
$dbh = null;
```

This only outputs "event happend 45 years ago" on the last notification...

Comment: You need to send a unix timestamp value to humanTiming, not a formatted string, otherwise you'll end up with the unix base date of 1st Jan 1970..... 45 years ago

Comment: `echo 'event happened '.humanTiming(strtotime($time)).' ago';`

Comment: That works but it still only displays it on the last notification and not the other ones..

Comment: Move your `echo 'event happened....` ___inside___ your `while` loop

Comment: Thank you very much make this an answer and i'll check it